# How do I stop system monitor from being transparent?

Tags: system-monitor

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 and system monitor isn't working properly. I cannot resize the window and the white background/transparent is missing when I go the the Resources tab.

[image]

Comment: The transparency looks like a bug in the theme not applying properly, try changing theme's or using unity tweak tool to apply the theme settings again.

Comment: Is this a conky setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when I added the gnome3 ppa, so I had to remove the ppa and reinstall gnome-system-monitor from scratch

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for that - It was getting really annoying. How did you know it was the gnome3 ppa that was playing up?

Comment: Because 14.04 doesn't have the issue by default, but after I added gnome3 ppa, and I ended up having the same issue that you did

Answer (score 4):

open terminal and type/paste:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

DONE, Worked for me.

Comment: It seems odd that a setting called `scrollbar-mode` would influence the background transparency.

Comment: This fixed multiple transparency issues in Ubuntu 15.04 with the Paper GTK theme

Answer (score 0):

Move your mouse pointer up to "System monitor". 
There, if you click *on top* of the words you see a menu. On the left side of the words you will also see three clickable "gadgets"; click the middle one and you will get back a resizable window.
The same will happen if you *double-click* the bar to the right of the words.

Can't help with the transparency... Not seen that option anywhere.