# Ubuntu 14.10 Some windows with transparent background

Tags: unity, 14.10, transparency

Some windows are behaving strangely by having a transparent background. ie system monitor in the image.

[image]

edit:
Is not only the system monitor, here an example with gedit:
[image]

Comment: why did you unaccepted my answer after having it accepted ? please give feedback

Comment: @edwardtorvalds After implementing your solution the problem was solve in the case of the system monitor. However I then find out that other windows still present the same behavior.

Comment: hey copy this file /etc/apt/sources on your system.list and give me the link ! ill have to look at it. besides tell me whether or not you use a software called compizsettings ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds here the [list](http://justpaste.it/i0v5) and yes I'm using compizsettings.

Comment: if you have gmail account. come to google plus we can discuss in chat there. link to my google+ profile is in on this website profile

Comment: hey sorry i missed your chat on google plus. please come again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rebuild your sources.list file
go to this [website](http://harishnavnit.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/fix-the-gpg-warning-using-y-ppa-manager/)
here you can make your sources.list file again.

**make sure you dont add Gnome PPA this time.**

select all that applies to you, except for **Backports - Unsupported Updates** and **Proposed - Pre-released Updates**. **Make you sure you select only those PPAs of softwares you have installed.**
Then copy the list generated and paste all of it sources.list file(you can open sources.list file by `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`). Make sure that you overwrite that file so that old content in it are removed.

Also you have to copy and paste all commands in the "Getting the GPG keys:" section one by one.

OR
[you can use Y-PPA manager for this.](http://harishnavnit.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/fix-the-gpg-warning-using-y-ppa-manager/)

Comment: The OP never said that he had installed Gnome3, so how can you be sure that it is related to that PPA?

Comment: @DanJohansen I had this same issue, when i removed the Gnome PPA the problem was solved ! have a look at this question on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485987/how-do-i-stop-system-monitor-from-being-transparent

Comment: The one you referenced to, was from a completely new install, where they told him to install that PPA to fix it. I never had it happen to me, but what would the solution be, without the PPA?

Comment: @DanJohansen I dont think it is something wrong to try this answer. besides if its wrong to suggest answer, i'll delete it !

Comment: That's true, but it solely depends on him even having that PPA. If he does not, this answer is irrelevant. :)

Comment: @DanJohansen ill delete this answer after he comments that his problem was not solved by this method.

Comment: @AlBahnsen you can also try this method to set opacity to 1: http://askubuntu.com/a/544714/294611  and this one http://askubuntu.com/a/530172/294611 make sure you do it such that you are removing transparency. besides join me on Google+ i can try to solve your problem in real time through chat. (visit my profile on this site for Google+ profile link)